# Model in sencha (array/object)

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

{ name: 'status', type: 'object' },

This is the fields in a model.

Can i define status.status1="value1", status.status2="value2" and so on..
if yes...then how?

If this is not possible, then can i use array in type??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, what you're looking for is a [store](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store). Here's an example:

```
Ext.define('AppName.store.Statuses', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        model: 'AppName.model.ModelName',
        data: [
            { name: 'name1', status: 'status1' },
            { name: 'name2', status: 'status2' },
            { name: 'name3', status: 'status3' },

        ]
    }
});
```

The above code would go in a `store` directory within your app folder, in a file called StoreName.js. Here, the data is hard coded in, but a store is generally used to load data through an AJAX call. See [the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) for more information about that. The store is generally named as the plural of the model name. For example, if your model was defined as Status, then the store would be named Statuses.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just set the field type to 'auto', see [this Sencha forum post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?137949-Can-I-make-a-Model-Field-Type-array)